# Problema con options_from_collection_for_select Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy teniendo problemas con lo siguiente, que me demora en cargar la pagina cuando la actualizo. Si yo cambio la variable ":fullname" por la variable ":id" (que seria lo que se muestra en el select option) carga rápido. Affiliate.actives me retorna los afiliados donde el campo 'active' es true. "fullname" es un campo de la tabla Affiliate, no realiza ningún calculo. La tabla affiliate debe tener aproximadamente 500 registros. Alguna solución?

Opción lenta:

> select_tag "affiliate", options_from_collection_for_select(Affiliate.actives, :id, :fullname), class: "form-control"

Opción rápida:

> select_tag "affiliate", options_from_collection_for_select(Affiliate.actives, :id, :id), class: "form-control"

Asociacion del modelo Affiliate:

> ## == Associations
>
> belongs_to :person, inverse_of: :affiliate

Comment: ¿qué tanto más se demora? no me queda claro cuál es la versión rápida y cuál es la lenta ¿puedes poner ambas? ¿que te retorna `Affiliate.actives`? ¿hay muchos registros ahí?¿has revisado la [docu](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) para verificar que efectivamente estés usando el helper como corresponde? ¿`fullname` es una variable de `Affiliate` o es un método que realiza algún cálculo? más info, por favor. Saludos

Comment: Ahí edite la pregunta con la mayor cantidad de información para que puedas ayudarme. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

De primeras, no se ve que podría estar causando la lentitud. 500 registros no creo que sea una cifra muy alta. De todas formas, las cosas que se me vienen a la mente que deberían mejorar tus tiempos de carga:

- No se si tengas muchos más campos en tu modelo de `Affiliates`, pero para no traer información que no vayas a utilizar, selecciona sólo los campos que necesites (Detalle: considera realizar las consultas en tu controlador y asignarlas a una variable en vez de consultar directo en la vista. La diferencia es el orden en tu código, aparte que puedes llegar a reutilizar ese código en otras vistas del mismo controlador donde puedas necesitar dicha variable. En el fondo, seguir el patrón MVC)

```
# Controlador
@active_affiliates = Affiliate.actives.select(:id, :fullname)
# Vista
options_from_collection_for_select(@active_affiliates, :id, :fullname)
```

- Considera crear una migración donde agregues [un índice](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) al campo `active`.
- En caso que los datos no cambien muy seguido, podrías considerar [cachearlos](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) para que carguen más rápido.

```
# Controlador:
#
# En caso que toda la plataforma cargue los mismos datos
cache_key = 'active_affiliates'
# Ahora, si existe una condición en la cual no siempre esta consulta retornaría
# los mismos valores, deberías hacer una key que cambie dependiendo de la
# condición. Aquí como ejemplo, el caso que cada usuario recibiera distintos
# datos.
cache_key = "active_affiliates_#{current_user.id}"
# Le puse expirar en una hora, pero ahí tu puedes ajustar el tiempo en cuanto
# quieres que expire. Otra opción es que pongas un callback en tu modelo donde
# llame a Rails.cache.delete con el mismo key, para que a la próxima llamada a 
# fetch refresque los datos.
@active_affiliates = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, expires_in: 1.hour) do
  Affiliate.actives.select(:id, :fullname)
end
```

Comment: Yo tengo generado un scope como podria seleccionar de alli solo los campos que necesito? el scope es el siguiente--- scope :provider_type_asc, -> {joins(:provider_type, :person).where("provider_type_id in (1, 23)").order("description, people.fullname")}

Comment: He probado con lo que me has dicho pero no ha mejorada en nada el rendimiento..

Comment: Si cachear datos no te ayudó, que es lo más rápido que podrías acceder a tus datos, ya que los carga directo de la memoria, entonces lo más probable es que sea algo no relacionado con esa línea. Revisa el log si te da alguna pista (o agrégalo a tu pregunta). Si remueves el select de la vista ¿te carga rápido nuevamente? ¿ocupas esos datos de affiliate en otra parte de tu código? podrías ocupar `pry-byebug` y comenzar a depurar la vista para investigar por qué razón pueda estar sucediendo. La verdad no sé de qué forma más pueda ayudarte, pero la info que entregas no veo que sea suficiente.

Comment: Respecto a tu scope, agrega el select en alguna parte de la cadena de tu consulta `scope :provider_type_asc, -> { joins(:provider_type, :person).where("provider_type_id in (1, 23)").order("description, people.fullname").select(:id, :fullname) }`. Ahora que lo pienso, podrías agregar a tu pregunta los modelos involucrados en tu consulta, como se relacionan y la consulta en sí. Pero insisto, con el caché solo se debería demorar cuando carga por primera vez, para las siguientes cargar ya no debería hacerlo.

Comment: Ahi agregue una foto de la DB para que sea mas simple. Si remuevo el select de la vista me carga rapido, como asi tambien cuando me carga rapido cuando en vez de mostrar el nombre muestro solo los id en los options del select

Comment: Para este caso en particular, creo que importan más los modelos que las tablas. No me interesa tanto los atributos, sino saber cómo conectaste los modelos unos entre otros, cómo está ejecutada esa consulta `Affiliate.actives` y qué modelos están involucrados en la ejecución de ésa. Si esto debe ser un problema de rails, no de la BD.

Comment: Affiliates.active la realizo con un scope de la siguiente manera:  :actives, -> { joins(:person).where( active: true ).order("people.fullname") }

Comment: Ahi edite la pregunta y agregue la asociacion del modelo Affiliate